# Webkit mask with SVG

Tags: css, svg, mask

I have a little problem with a webpage that I'm developing.

I use a .SVG file to mask a part of the image.

It works properly on Firefox, Safari but only works on Chrome under OS X.

I would like to understand why? Any ideas ?

Here is an example page where I got the same problem : http://girliemac.com/sandbox/mask.html

Thanks in advance,

Jk_

Comment: Any idea why you can clip an SVG file, but not an embedded SVG?  Suppose you used `url(#twitter-bird)` instead.  Any way for that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try experimenting with different values like this:

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: url(svg/twitter-bird-new.svg) 100 100 0 0 round round;
```

Seems like it has something to do with scaling. Why? Because it's still in its experimental phase.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-webkit-mask-box-image

Comment: Thanks for this ! It's still experimental you right. But I'm trying to find the best -cross browser- solution for masking image. When I use border-radius, I get error with Chrome so I think about SVG. I'm going to try with canvas masking. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This looks good, but if you jQuerify in Chrome and do a hit test:

```
$(".avatar").on("click", function(){ console.log("works!");});
```

You can click the rest of the box... anyways for me to do something like this and be able to click UNDERNEATH? I am trying to have a circle masked... but I don't want to click the circle on the top... I want to click the things underneath.. Such as if you have a dime on top of a quarter and you can see the edge of the larger coin like a tray...